# Problem with Unused Audio-Channels in QuickTime Capture

Tags: audio, video-capture, quicktime, qtkit

I have written an application that captures audio and video from multiple devices simultaneously, using the QTKit capture APIs a while ago.

However, I have learned that from time to time, the media captured from DV camcorders *appears* to not have any associated audio. In fact, the audio track is well present in the file, but the channels are set to "unused" in QuickTime Player Pro — hence the silence.

Since I am not comfortable exposing my users to such shenanigans, I want to post-flight my recordings and fix the channel-layout automatically, if needed.

Unfortunately, I have a hard time figuring out how!

My question is two-fold:

1. Is it at all possible to detect if the audio-channels of a track are marked as "unused" from QTKit?
2. Since I think that the answer to the above is "no", I've been digging around the structure of some movie files that are working correctly with "Atom Inspector" — so far without any success:
   What/Where is the QuickTime Atom where this info is stored?
   I can see the correct number of channels in the `stsd` Atom (contained in the `stbl` Atom) but I don't see where any mapping occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: Doesn't look like it.

You'll have to use the `QTGetTrackPropertyInfo` API with `kQTPropertyClass_Audio, kQTAudioPropertyID_ChannelLayout` to get a channel layout. If the returned `AudioChannelLayout` structure contains a tag != 0, you can resolve that via `AudioFormatGetPropertyInfo` with `kAudioFormatProperty_ChannelLayoutForTag`; otherwise, the `AudioChannelDescription` field will be valid, with `mChannelLabel` set to `kAudioChannelLabel_Unused` (0). Of course, all this only works in 32 bit. Don't forget to `#include <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>`

Second question:
The stsd atom of the audio track should contain a 'chan' extension. This extension appears to be a UInt32 set to zero, followed by an `AudioChannelLayout` structure. It doesn't seem to be documented in either the QT file spec nor the MP4 spec.

Good luck!